# In docker container connect from inside to local apache not happening

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

#### Problem

I visit page by browser `http://localhost`, I see content of `public` folder.
The problem is, when I run tests, curl won't connect with message:

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)

I run tests by command:

> docker-compose run --rm php php vendor/bin/behat

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    image: webdevops/php-apache:ubuntu-16.04
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    working_dir: /app
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=local
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=localhost
      - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/public
    ports:
      - 80:80
  composer:
    image: composer/composer
    working_dir: /app
    volumes_from:
      - php
```

#### My env

- Mac OSX 10.11.6
- Docker for mac: 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661)

#### Summary

I probably ommited something in configuration? Could you help me, find problem.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried with `curl http://$ip_address_of_your_physical_machine` from running container ?

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with the resolution of the "localhost". To which address does it resolve on the container? To which on the host?

Comment: The hostname "localhost" is special, it might be part of the problem in this scenario. If you can, try with another one just to see if it generally would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker adds a default network called `docker0` and your host takes the IP address `172.17.0.1`. You can test this by typing `ifconfig` in your host.

If you run a new container without specifying a different network, it attaches to the default network with an IP address: `172.17.0.X`. This way, if you want to access a web server running on the host from inside a container, try to:

```
curl http://172.17.0.1:[port]
```

Comment: Didn't know about default. I thinked, if I run inside container command like `docker-compose run --rm php php vendor/bin/behat` (on container php, i have apache too) it will call the address of this container and connect to apache. Using this IP, helped.